# Unattended build of linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, compiling

**Goal:**

I am trying to automate the 4.0.4 kernel build to provision it to multiple machines. Since AUFS no longer ships in "extras" package, I am compiling it as well, and then adding via make menuconfig options.

**My question is:**

How do I pre-select the AUFS option without having to manually select it in GUI?

**Additional info:**

Building as described [here](http://zackreed.me/articles/90-ubuntu-14-04-with-4-0-4-kernel-and-latest-aufs-from-source)

**Have tried:**

`make olddefconfig`

`echo "CONFIG_AUFS = y" >> .config`

with no luck.

Comment: manually select it in the gui then track the generated .config as a file in a git repo.  between builds, you can reset the git repo, or at least that file.